# How to call a method asynchronously in PyQt5 using Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, pyqt, pyqt5

How to call a method asynchronously in PyQt5 using Python3?

I have tried to use a signal to do it.

```
import sys
from time import sleep

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    asyncFuncSignal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("loading...")

        # Trying to call 'self.asyncFunc' asynchronously
        self.asyncFuncSignal.connect(self.asyncFunc)
        self.asyncFuncSignal.emit()

        print("loaded")

    def asyncFunc(self):
        # Doing something hard that takes time
        # I have used 'sleep' to implement the delay
        sleep(2)

        self.label.setText("done")
        print("asyncFunc finished")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This program tries to finish `asyncFunc` before writing `"loaded"`. But I would like the program to finish `initUi` immediately with shown `loading...` in the label and after that the text `done` appears in 2 seconds.

What is the best and the shortest way to do it?

It's said here http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html I can use queued connections but I haven't found an example how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

`PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection` may help. Just replace

```
self.asyncFuncSignal.connect(self.asyncFunc)
```

with

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

...

self.asyncFuncSignal.connect(self.asyncFunc, Qt.QueuedConnection)
```

Comment: how would you do this if the asyn function was called from a button?

Comment: I guess at least you can call `.emit()` of your signal variable inside of another function bounded to the button in the standard way. Haven't you tried it yet?

Comment: I just came back to this and this no longer seems to work - at least i just tried the code 1:1 with Python 3.8.6 and PyQt5 5.15.6 - the label starts empty, freezes for 2 seconds and then shows "done"